# Photoswipe adding margin to lightbox image

Tags: photoswipe

I'm using http://photoswipe.com/ here: http://www.michelperezphoto.com/.

Trying to add padding or margin so that the image displayed in lightbox does not occupy the whole width and or height of screen...

Tried this:
    .pswp__item {
        margin: 5%;
    }

But now the lightbox image is not centered ...its slightly offcenter to the right...

Any insight would be greatly appreciated...

Cheers.....

Comment: If you would be using Fancybox, then it would be extremely simple, just by adding padding to the container (carousel slide).

Answer (score 2):

I have a border-radius and drop shadow applied to my images, using the margin technique above masked my images and didn't look good. I found a better solution:

```
.pswp__img {
    transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps someone, I got desired effect using this:

```
@media (min-width: 900px) { 
 .pswp__item {
    margin: 5% 5% 5% 0%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now there are two options for lightbox. `padding` and `paddingFn` https://photoswipe.com/options/#padding, https://photoswipe.com/options/#paddingfn

For example

```js
const lightbox = new PhotoSwipeLightbox({
  // ...
  paddingFn: (viewportSize, itemData, index) => {
          return {
            top: viewportSize.x > 600 ? 82 : 0,
            bottom: viewportSize.x > 600 ? 100 : 0,
            left: viewportSize.x < 600 ? 10 : 0,
            right: viewportSize.x < 600 ? 10 : 0
          }
   }
})
```